# How is namevhost derived in output of "apache2ctl -S" command?

Tags: apache-2.4

When I run `apache2ctl -S` on my server, I mostly get something like this for each website on the server:

`port * namevhost www.websitedomain.org (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/websitedomain.conf:29)`

Notice that the string after `namevhost` matches the domain name for the web site.

However, there are a few dozen websites on the server that report the web server's host name followed by the domain name for the `namevhost` setting, like this:

`port * namevhost server_hostname.server_domain_name.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/anotherwebsitedomain.conf:29)`

I'm trying to figure out why these sites are showing `server_hostname.server_domain_name.com` for `namevhost` instead of something the usual `www.anotherwebstiedomain.com`.

I've grepped through the apache configuration files and I do not see that `server_hostname.server_domain_name.com` is anywhere in the configuration. So where might this string for `namevhost` be coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Apache 2.4 [Name-based Virtual Host Support](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html) documentation:

> If you omit the `ServerName` directive from any name-based virtual host,
>   the server will default to a fully qualified domain name (FQDN)
>   derived from the system hostname. This implicitly set server name can
>   lead to counter-intuitive virtual host matching and is discouraged.

How this is done exactly is explained in the documentation of the [`ServerName` Directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#servername):

> If no `ServerName` is specified, the server attempts to deduce the
>   client visible hostname by first asking the operating system for the
>   system hostname, and if that fails, performing a reverse lookup on an
>   IP address present on the system.

That's where the hostname you see comes from.

Answer (score 0):

The domains showing up as `server_hostname.server_domain.com` do not have the apache `ServerName` directive set.